# How to catch the error if an <object> fails to load?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I want to display some content in an object tag, but I want to show a specific error message to the user if the target of the object fails to load. Here's my code:

```
<object id="foo"></object>
<script>
    document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('error', function() {
        alert('error');
    });
    document.getElementById('foo').data = 'http://localhost/doesnotexist';
</script>
```

The error handler never gets run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `document.getElementById()` doesn't find the element it will return `null`, so you should test for that. Not finding the element will not fire the `error` event.

Comment: You shouldn't display the error inside the `<object>` tag, if you want to be W3C compliant. Use another Element. Then it's like `Element.innerHTML = 'Your Request Failed'` in your `'error'` Event.

Comment: Neither of these responses answers my question.

Comment: I spent about 30 minutes on this and didn't get anywhere. It sometimes fires the error handle once, sometimes twice, and the handler provides an Event object not an Error object, which doesn't show a proper error message. Further, my network inspector never shows an attempt to load the 404 resource. This is very strange so good luck.

Comment: I can't get it to trigger the event at all, so I'd be very interested in knowing whatever you did to get it to fire once or twice. I tried the code I posted in both Firefox and Chrome. I did find this, which suggests that it may be a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445557

Comment: I finally switched to using <iframe> instead, which sends the load event on both successful load and error.

Comment: Did anybody get anywhere with this problem? I am also stuck on it..